# Are all fonts supports in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I have installed and used following font

- Antartida Rounded Black
- Antartida Rounded Black Italic
- Antartida Rounded Bold
- Antartida Rounded Bold Italic
- Antartida Rounded Light
- Antartida Rounded Light Italic
- Antartida Rounded Medium
- Antartida Rounded Medium Italic

and used code to add font

```
Typeface tp = TypeFaces.get(context, "font/AntartidaRounded-Black.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(tp);
```

### to set font

```
public class TypeFaces {
private static final String TAG = "Typefaces";

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
synchronized (cache) {
if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
try {
Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), assetPath);
cache.put(assetPath, t);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath + "' because " + e.getMessage());
return null;
}
}
return cache.get(assetPath);
}
}
}
```

to use

```
Typeface tf = TypeFaces.get(c, "font/AntartidaRounded-Bold.ttf");
```

is there any wrong in this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your fonts installed under the assets folder?

Comment: Yes, its there in Asset folder only

Answer (score 0):

The Typeface class does not have a `get` method, so I'm not even sure where you're getting that from...

What you're looking for is [Typeface#createFromAsset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29).